# When does blank space count?

Tags: spacing

I suppose this is too general of a question, but why does

```
 \underbar{word}
```

give different answer from

```
 \underbar{ word}
```

and then additional blanks do not count

```
 \underbar{     word}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rule about spaces is quite simple (or maybe not too simple).

When TeX reads a line of input it is in one of three *states*: state *N* (new line), state *S* (skipping blanks) or state *M* (middle of line).

It's clear that at the beginning of a line it is in state *N*; when in this state, any blank space (TeXnically a character with character code 10, usually space and TAB) is ignored. This state stops to become state *M* upon finding a non blank character.

If the next character is the end-of-line character (more precisely, a character having category code 5), a `\par` token is generated and TeX reenters state *N* for the next line, throwing away anything that possibly follows that character.

When TeX is in state *M* it generates character tokens for each character it finds unless

1. the next character is a space, or
2. the next character is the end-of-line character, or
3. the next character is the escape character (the backslash).

In case 1 TeX generates a space token and enters state *S*. In case 2 TeX inserts a space token, throws away what remains on the line and enters state *N* for reading the next line. In case 3 TeX proceeds to form a symbolic token and there are two subcases:

4. the next character is a letter (TeXnically, a character with category code 11)
5. the next character is any other character

In subcase 4 TeX forms the symbolic token's name by accumulating characters until they are letters and, upon finding a non letter, it enters state *S*. In subcase 5, the symbolic token's name is the single non letter (this is the case of `\,` or `\\`, for instance) and remains in state *M*, unless that non letter was a space, in which case it enters state *S*.

When TeX is in state *S*, blank space characters are ignored until finding any character that is not a blank space character, which triggers state *M* again.

The above discussion is not as  general as possible, but adequate for the normal status of category codes.

Let's examine your examples. First

```
\underbar{word}
```

where `\` triggers state *M* and, since `u` is a letter, we are in subcase 4, so the symbolic token `\underbar` is generated, because `{` is not a letter. So we have the following tokens

```
\underbar • { • w • o • r • d • }
```

(here the spaces are not significant and `•` separates tokens).

In the second example

```
\underbar{ word}
```

we're in the same situation, but the space after `{` generates a space token and makes TeX enter state *S*, which is turned into state *M* by the `w`. So the formed tokens are

```
\underbar • { • <SP> • w • o • r • d • }
```

(where `<SP>` denotes a space token). The third example

```
\underbar{     word}
```

gives the same result, because upon seeing the first space character after `{`, TeX enters state *S* after having generated a space token.

The same as in the first example would have happened with

```
\underbar {word}
```

because the space stops the formation of the control sequence name and, according to the rule, it enters state *S* *without* generating a space token. The only dubious case is

```
\⍽⍽
```

where now `⍽` denotes a space character (just to make clear that there are two of them). But according to the rule explained in subcase 5, this generates the token `\⍽` and TeX enters state *S*. Thus typing `\⍽`, `\⍽⍽` or `\⍽⍽⍽` is just the same.

Answer (score 8):

From "The not so short introduction to LaTeX  2e":

> "Whitespace" characters, such as blank or tab, are treated uniformly as "space" by LaTeX . Several consecutive whitespace characters are treated as one "space". 
>   Whitespace at the start of a line is generally ignored, and a
>   single line break is treated as "whitespace". 
>   An empty line between two lines of text defines the end of a paragraph.
>   Several empty lines are treated the same as one empty line.

Bacially, multiple spaces are treated as a single space.